# How shift graph in Android's Canvas

Tags: android

I draw a graph with canvas in android, but I want to shift it to left or right side. I don't want to scroll it, I just want to shift it in one page by which you can see the graph is shifting lively. 
I would be appreciated if any body help me.

Comment: "shift it in one page by which you can see the graph is shifting lively" that statement needs some work, I have no idea what you're trying to say. Some source code might help too.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a an answer to this question as well. I have a solution but it is to slow and uses a lot of CPU time.  I am drawing two graphs with a width of 200 pixels and have the values stored in an array. I just shift the values in the array and moves them into a path.
I would be nice to have a solution where the canvas gets shifted by 1 pixel to the left and the 200th column gets drawn with the new value. With both paths are empty it takes about 2ms (Droid Incredible) to draw the paths. When the 2 paths are filled up it can take more than 40ms. This would give still 25fps but I would like to run other threads at the same time and don't want to waste CPU time.
Here is the source.

public class OSCI extends View

{
    Integer[] codebuffer = new Integer[200];
    Integer[] codebuffer1 = new Integer[200];
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    long start;
    int code=0;

`// private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
public OSCI(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    Arrays.fill(codebuffer, 1);
    Arrays.fill(codebuffer1, 1);
}

public OSCI(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);;
    Arrays.fill(codebuffer, 1);
    Arrays.fill(codebuffer1, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 70);

    Paint paint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Path path1 = new Path();
    path1.moveTo(0, 70);

    int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(codebuffer));
    if(max==0)max=1;
    for (int a = 0; a < codebuffer.length; a++)
    {
        if (codebuffer[a] < 0)code=0;
        code = 70 * codebuffer[a] / max;
        path.lineTo(a * 2 + 2, 70 - code);
        path1.lineTo(a * 2+ 2, 70 - (codebuffer1[a]));
    }
    start=(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    canvas.drawPath(path1, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint1);

    Log.v(TAG, " "+(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-start));
}

public void newValue(int value, int valuew)
{

    System.arraycopy(codebuffer, 1, codebuffer, 0, 199);
    codebuffer[199] = value;

    System.arraycopy(codebuffer1, 1, codebuffer1, 0, 199);
    codebuffer1[199] = valuew;

    invalidate();
}`

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. can you let me know where you call newValue(int value, int valuew) method please.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer but I have 2 questions. At the first time, when you call newValue(int value, int valuew) method in your code. Second, to see shift movement are you using thread or time and how you use it.